# Busca de dados sem formatação sqlserver com select

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho um campo na tabela `Clientes` com nome `CPFCNPJ` porém seus dados estão formatados com *pontos* e *hifens* e gostaria de fazer um *SELECT* formatando esses dados sem a pontuação.

É possível realizar esse tipo de busca no SQL Server?

Comment: O que deseja é que no resultado da consulta seja retirada a formatação *ou* o objetivo é pesquisar sem a formatação? O enunciado está dúbio... Poderia postar exemplo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Consultando

Executando uma consulta, caso no seu banco for somente números:

```
SELECT CPFCNPJ
FROM tabela
WHERE CPFCNPJ = REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE('111.222.333-00', '.', ''), '-', ''), '/', '' )
```

Retirando os caracteres para consulta

```
SELECT CPFCNPJ
FROM tabela
WHERE REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE(CPFCNPJ, '.', ''), '-', ''), '/', '' ) = '1112223300'
```

---

#### Aplicando

Caso existam no seu banco formatados e queria "converte-los":

```
UPDATE tabela
SET CPFCNPJ = REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE(CPFCNPJ, '.', ''), '-', ''), '/', '' )
```

---

#### Links úteis:

[REPLACE](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: no meu caso queria tirar a pontuação para que o usuário não tenha que digitar pontos e hifens para localizar tal cliente.         https://i.imgur.com/2paRRhW.png   esta assim os dados em meu bd

Comment: @AlltairMentor adicionei o 2o select em "consultando" na minha resposta.

Comment: Obrigado pelas instruções rbz porém quando realizo a consulta para retirar os caracteres ela volta nula sem nenhum resultado. É necessário declarar o cpfoucnpj? obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Pode fazer de uma forma mais "parecida" com `RegEx`:

```
DECLARE @Input VARCHAR(100) = 'abc1234-6a,9*isd(yt«?56AYZ'

WHILE PATINDEX('%[^a-z]%', @Input) > 0
    SET @Input = STUFF(@Input, PATINDEX('%[^a-z]%', @Input), 1, '')

PRINT @Input
```

Resultado:

> abcaisdytAYZ

Outra forma é criar uma função que lhe retorne apenas letras (para poder utilizar em consultas):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_DevolveLetras](@input VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN 
    WHILE PATINDEX('%[^a-z]%', @input) > 0
    SET @input = STUFF(@input, PATINDEX('%[^a-z]%', @input), 1, '')
    RETURN @input
END
```

Forma de utilização:

```
SELECT [dbo].[fn_DevolveLetras]('abc1234-6a,9*isd(yt«?56AYZ')
```